# How to `trap` in `bats`?

Tags: bats-core

I have the following in some of my tests:

```sh
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'echo @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ >&3' INT TERM HUP EXIT # trap is really meant to `rm -rf ${tmpdir}`
```

I'm expecting the `echo` to be executed but not seeing the output.

What do my tests need to do to clean up after themselves?

Answer (score 0):

`bats` does not support tests with `trap`.

What can be done is:

```
setup() {
  BATS_TMPDIR="$(mktemp -d)"
}

teardown() {
  rm -rf "${BATS_TMPDIR}"
}
```

If you're like me and have temporary directories that are created inside functions, the following can then be used: `tmpdir="$(mktemp -d --tmpdir="${BATS_TMPDIR}")"`. That will get cleaned up when `${BATS_TMPDIR}` is cleaned up in the `teardown` function.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with the desired outcome:

`trap '[ "${FUNCNAME[0]}" == "$BATS_TEST_NAME" ] && echo yo' ERR`

Where the `echo yo` does cleanup and is also present in the code, as this just gets error cases. The check on function name excludes traps firing early, e.g. in anything under `run` or calls to underlying functions.

`RETURN` didn't execute in case of errors. EXIT caused the test not to run at all.

:S